# How to dlopen an unknown version of a library

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to load libreadline.so.  My code works fine if I give the version number explicitly as in "libreadline.so.6" but fails if I just give "libreadline.so", presumably its just trying to open the file name I give directly.  To avoid a future failure when a new version appears, I call dlopen in a loop with the version number counting down to zero.  This works and always picks up the latest version of libreadline.

My question is, is there a correct, or better, way of doing this?

I see libreadline.so.6 is a link to libreadline.so.6.3, its a pity they cant have a link from libreadline.so to the latest version.

Comment: How about  put the version number in a configure file, and then you can fetch the right version.

Comment: Maybe follow links in two steps, libreadline.so probably links to libreadline.so.6, which then links to the actual library binary.

Comment: Version number in config file: Yes, of course that works, and then resort to the loop if the version has been changed and the config file has not been altered.  People shouldn't have to go round editing files for unrelated applications when a library is updated.  My gut feeling is that there is a "proper" way to do this!!

Comment: That's the problem, there is no "libreadline.so" (that dlopen can find).

Comment: I don't think this is just a libreadline problem as there is no "libc.so" or "libm.so" either.  And readline is a pretty major library.

Comment: It's probably a case of packagers choosing not to include the `libreadline.so` symlink in the package so they can install multiple major versions at the same time without file clashes in the packages. Your code should probably only attempt to load major versions it knows it is compatible with, since an increment in the SONAME value typically means some older interfaces have been removed, or have changed incompatibly.

Comment: What distribution are you using? IMO making assumptions about filesystem layout hard coded is a bad idea. Though I'm biased, because it would fail miserably on NixOS which is what I use.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend blindly looking for the newest major version. If the major version changes there are potentially breaking API changes and you should reevaluate your use of the library, change your code to look for the new major version and retest.

Comment: Thankyou, that last comment does make sense.  And new major versions of these big libraries do not appear very often.

Answer (score 0):

What about opening the directory which contains all the different files and then comparing the extensions of all files?